# DisconnectedContext was detected:Exception setting can be set for a project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When i run one of my vb project i get below warning message.

```
DisconnectedContext was detected
Message: Context 0x21b448' is disconnected.  Releasing the interfaces from the current context (context 0x21b2d8).This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all contexts/apartments stay alive until the applicationis completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that liveinside them.
```

A quick google search gave me result like it can be solved by disabling the exception "disconnectedContext ". So I did in menu->debug->exception, under manage debug assistants deselect disconnectedContext  and it solved the problem too.

But this setting is not project wise or visual studio wise. I found like this setting is saved in .suo file.Now I want this setting I made to be available for all users using the project. So how it can be set project wise so that all users using the project will be able to get disconnectedContext   setting disabled